Validation Errors in Login Page using Reactjs
I am getting the below validation errors in Login Page after Login button is clicked using Reactjs and I have also corrected all the spelling/typo mistakes in the codes. I am learning the react now and this is my first project so could you please help to sort out this issue.
Login.jsx
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Validation from "./LoginValidation";

function Login() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);
  const handleInput = (event) => {
    setValues((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [event.target.name]: [event.target.value],
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setErrors(Validation(values));
  };

  return (
    <div className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center bg-primary vh-100">
      <div className="bg-white p-3 rounded w-25">
        <h2>Sign In</h2>
        <form action="" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="email">
              <strong>Email</strong>
            </label>
            <input
              type="email"
              placeholder="Enter Email"
              name="email"
              onChange={handleInput}
              {...(errors.email && (
                <span className="text-danger">{errors.email}</span>
              ))}
              className="form-control rounded-0"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="password">
              <strong>Password</strong>
            </label>
            <input
              type="password"
              placeholder="Enter Password"
              name="password"
              onChange={handleInput}
              {...(errors.password && (
                <span className="text-danger">{errors.password}</span>
              ))}
              className="form-control rounded-0"
            />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success w-100 rounded-0">
            Log In
          </button>
          <p>You are agree to our terms and policies</p>
          <Link
            to="/signup"
            className="btn btn-default border w-100 bg-light rounded-0 text-decoration-none"
          >
            Create Account
          </Link>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;

LoginValidation.jsx
function Validation(values) {
  let error = {};
  const email_pattern = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
  const password_pattern = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$/;

  if (values.email === "") {
    error.email = "Name should not be empty";
  } else if (!email_pattern.test(values.email)) {
    error.email = "Email didn't match";
  } else {
    values.email = "";
  }

  if (values.password === "") {
    error.password = "Name should not be empty";
  } else if (!password_pattern.test(values.password)) {
    error.password = "Email didn't match";
  } else {
    values.password = "";
  }
  return error;
}

export default Validation;

I have attached the error images for the reference.



Typo.  event has no taget property, but it does have a target property.

Thanks for the help, but validations are still not working

If you've corrected the issue being asked about above and have encountered a separate issue, that's likely worth a new Stack Overflow question.  In that question, please provide a [mcve] of the problem and indicate specifically what isn't working as expected and what debugging you have done.

Okay, I will raise a new question

@bhuvana Validations might still be failing because of name="passwrord" which should be "password", note that it's typed wrong in multiple places.

I have corrected all typo mistakes

@bhuvana: Regarding the updated code... It looks like you're trying to use <span className="text-danger">{errors.email}</span> as a prop in an <input> element.  Why?  Did you mean to put that outside of the <input> element, such as after it?

It's  outside the  element and It's working now. Thanks once again.

You misspelled here:
 setValues((prev) => ({ ...prev, [event.taget.name]: [event.taget.value] }));
Replace With:
✅  setValues((prev) => ({ ...prev, [event.target.name]: [event.target.value] }));

I have corrected and tried it, but validations are still not working

  if (
    error.email === "" &&
    error.password === "" &&
    !email_pattern.test(values.email) &&
    !password_pattern.test(values.password)
  ) {
    return "Validation Failed!";
  } else {
    return "Validation Passed!";
  }
}
export default Validation;

